# Bash: Regex for SVN Conflicts

Tags: regex, bash, svn

So I'm trying to write a regex to use for a grep command on an SVN status command. I want only files with conflicts to be displayed, and if it's a tree conflict, the extra information SVN provides about it (which is on a line with a > character).

So, here's my description of how SVN outputs lines with conflicts, and then I'll show my regex:

```
[Single Char Code][Spaces][Letter "C"][Space]Filename
[Spaces][Letter "C"][Space]Filename
[Letter "C"][Space]Filename
```

This is what I have so far to try and get the proper regex. The second part, after the OR condition, works fine to get the tree conflict extra line. It's the first part, where I'm trying to get lines with the letter C under very specific conditions.

Anyway, I'm not exactly the greatest with Regex, so some help here (plus an explanation of what I'm doing wrong, so I can learn from this) would be great.

```
CONFLICTS=($(svn status | grep "^(.)*C\s\|>"))
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This regex should match your lines :

```
CONFLICTS=$(svn status | grep '^[ADMRCXI?!~ ]\? *C')
```

- `^[ADMRCXI?!~ ]\?`: lines starting with zero or one `\?`status character `^[ADMRCXI?!~ ]`
- `*`zero or more spaces
- character `C`

I removed the extra parenthesis surrounding the command substitution.

Comment: `filename` doesn't want to be in that `grep` pattern and you should probably use single quotes (it doesn't matter here but it is good practice to get used to using them when you don't need variable expansion I think).

Comment: Thanks for you comment @EtanReisner. Updated.

Comment: `^[A-Za-z]` - no-no, you miss at least some chars from [:punct:]

Comment: Sorry i'm not a svn user. Updated the regex.

Comment: Thank you so much. Escaping the ? quantifier was the biggest area I was messing up. Can I ask why the tilde is used? Also, wouldn't the ! be includes with the rest of the group?

Comment: The `~` is a possibile char in svn status codes (from : http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svn.c.status.html). In the range of characters, `\?` does not need to be escaped, nor `\!` (due to single quotes) so i've just udpated the char list. All the chars in brackets are handled as literals.

Comment: You pattern is **still wrong** in some positions (compare with my draft). You can use my status output for debugging, if you don't have own

Comment: Again i'm not a svn user. My grep only translate patterns given by the OP.

Answer (score 1):

You have to read description of `svn st` output more deeply and try to get at least one Tree Conflict.

I'll start it for you:

```
> The first seven columns in the output are each one character wide:
>...
>     Seventh column: Whether the item is the victim of a tree conflict
>...
>    'C' tree-Conflicted
```

and note: theoretically *any* of these 7 columns can be non-empty

status for tree-conflict

```
 M      wc/bar.c
!     C wc/qaz.c
      >   local missing, incoming edit upon update
D       wc/qax.c
```

Dirty lazy draft of regexp

```
^[enumerate_all_chars_here]{6}C\s
```